# Can not query the json column with sqlachemy

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to query with in json column in postgresql with `flask-sqlalchemy`.
here is my code

```
house_ = House()
results = house_.query.filter(
            House.information['branch_name'].astext == 'release0'
            ).all()
```

I am not sure what is wrong.
I tried to use `.cast(Unicode)` instead of `astext` as well.

Getting error as below:

```
NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What's the type of `House.information`? If it's JSONB, it should work

Answer (score 6):

You shold use 'op'  method in your query, like this:

```
Session.query(Model).filter(Model.json_field.op('->')('KEY') == VALUE)
```

Also, you can use - >> JSON operator for auto-cast value to text. Also, you can read more about Postgresql JSON(B) operators :)